# Working with OpenLDAP 2.4 LDIF config backend

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, openldap

In OpenLDAP 2.4, the configuration has been moved into an LDIF backend called `cn=config`. The OpenLDAP documentation says "you should never edit any of the LDIF files directly. Configuration changes should be performed via LDAP operations..." but does not give details any further details.

There's lots of conflicting information and to make matters worse, distros, such as Redhat Linux and Ubuntu, have specific configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to edit the `cn=config` date: directly and indirectly. Indirect uses normal ldap tools, such as ldapmodify and ldapsearch, which provides the simplest and most logical approach. **HOWEVER, many distros use SASL to restrict access to just the root user on the local box**. Assuming, you have a preconfigured instance, you can easily change this:

**Enabling external access to cn=config**

1. `sudo -i` / `su -`
2. Create a new password:

   ```
   slappasswd
   ```
3. Copy result, including "{SSHA}"
4. Prepare `auth.ldif`. Replace `olcRootPW` with your password hash from last command

   ```
   dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
   changetype: modify
   replace: olcRootDN
   olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config 
   -
   replace: olcRootPW
   olcRootPW: {SSHA}jCMTRlz/iT4cw3CZno5z2PtCkJQbKrqK
   ```
5. Import LDIF:

   ```
   ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f auth.ldif
   ```
6. You may now connect externally (assuming you have network access), using any LDAP client. E.g.

   ```
   ldapsearch -b cn=config -D cn=admin,cn=config -H ldap://myldapserver -W
   ```
7. Configure SSL ASAP!

**Direct Mode**

In direct mode, you can edit the cn=config database (and any other database), even if `slapd` is down. This is through the use of `slapadd` and `slapcat` tools. You must pass the database suffix. For example:

```
slapcat -b cn=config
```

IMHO, direct mode is best used when you know the exact LDIF you need to apply. I rarely do, so I tend to use normal LDAP tools to add, replace, and delete configuration on the fly.