# OpenLDAP 2.4 Chain Overlay Minimal LDIF Configuration

Tags: configuration, openldap

There's almost no information about how Chain overlays are configured in OpenLDAP LDIF backend. What's the minimal configuration required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to work this out is by converting an old style configuration file into LDIF style. This show's quite a complex structure which isn't well documented.

The structure creates LDAP database entries in the frontend to intercept referrer responses.

To complicate matters, a schema validation conflicts with OpenLDAP's own configuration requirements (olcDbURI can not be used in the first entry). To work around this, the offline/direct modification must be made but remember that editing the LDIF directly with a text editor is strongly discouraged - See [Working with OpenLDAP 2.4 LDIF config backend](https://serverfault.com/questions/518151/working-with-openldap-2-4-ldif-config-backend)

If you're on Ubuntu/Debian, ensure you load the `back_ldap` module - [OpenLDAP Chain not found](https://serverfault.com/questions/518382/openldap-chain-not-found)

1. Create "chainoverlay.ldif":

   ```
   dn: olcOverlay=chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
   objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
   objectClass: olcChainConfig
   olcOverlay: chain
   olcChainCacheURI: FALSE
   olcChainMaxReferralDepth: 1
   olcChainReturnError: TRUE
   ```
2. As root, import indirectly:

   ```
   # ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f chainoverlay.ldif
   ```
3. Create "defaultldap.ldif":

   ```
   dn: olcDatabase=ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
   objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
   objectClass: olcChainDatabase
   olcDatabase: ldap
   ```
4. Import defaultldap.ldif offline (This is to work around schema validation):

   ```
   # service slapd stop
   # slapadd -b cn=config -l defaultldap.ldif
   ```
5. Fix a weird entry and perms:

   ```
   # rm "/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={-1}over.ldif"
   # chown -R openldap:openldap "/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config"
   ```
6. Start slapd:

   ```
   # service slapd start
   ```
7. Create a chain intercept configuration - chainedserver.ldif:

   ```
   dn: olcDatabase=ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
   objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
   objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
   objectClass: olcConfig
   objectClass: top
   objectClass: olcChainDatabase
   olcDatabase: ldap
   olcDbURI: ldap://areferredserver.com
   ```